# Create method for NSString

Tags: objective-c

I want to create a method in Obj C taking a NSString and checking if the string is capitalized. Where do I declare it, another .m file?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a category for it in the file that will use that method, or another new file if a lot of classes will be using it.

```
@interface NSString (Capitalized)
-(BOOL)isCapitalized;
@end
```